# How can I fix this error in my code for an assignment?

Tags: c++

Assignment:
Start with Assignment 3.0 (a previous assignment) and modify the function averageGrades() so that it does not take into account grades with the value -1. In this case, -1 indicates the assignment was not completed yet so it should not factor in the average.
I'm using a program called testbed to test my work. It acts like the user and compares the actual and expected results. I'm getting a rounding error on one test and passing others, and I'm not sure why:
Test 1
With one -1, there are 9 items to be averaged:
   90 + 86 + 95 + 76 + 92 + 83 + 100 + 87 + 91 = 800
   800 / 9 = 88.888 
Note we are working with integers here so the value gets truncated!

> Grade 1: 90
>   Grade 2: 86
>   Grade 3: 95
>   Grade 4: 76
>   Grade 5: 92
>   Grade 6: 83
>   Grade 7: 100
>   Grade 8: 87
>   Grade 9: 91
>   Grade 10: -1
>   Average Grade: 88%
>   Test 1 passed.

Test 2
There is one -1 in the list here, but it is in the middle.
   90 + 86 + 95 + 92 + 83 + 100 + 87 + 91 + 76 = 800
   800 / 9 = 88.888

> Grade 1: 90
>   Grade 2: 86
>   Grade 3: 95
>   Grade 4: -1
>   Grade 5: 92
>   Grade 6: 83
>   Grade 7: 100
>   Grade 8: 87
>   Grade 9: 91
>   Grade 10: 76
>   Average Grade: 89%\n
>   Exp: Average Grade: 88%\n
>   Test 2 failed.

Test 3
This is a special case. Since all the values are -1, the sum is 0.
However, if you try to compute the average, you will have 0/0.
Since we can't divide by zero, this will crash. You need to check
for this case with an IF statement

> Grade 1: -1
>   Grade 2: -1
>   Grade 3: -1
>   Grade 4: -1
>   Grade 5: -1
>   Grade 6: -1
>   Grade 7: -1
>   Grade 8: -1
>   Grade 9: -1
>   Grade 10: -1
>   Average Grade: ---%
>   Test 3 passed.
>   Failed 1/3 tests.
>   Finally: here's my code:

```
Please help with this C++ assignment I'm working on?
```

Start with Assignment 3.0 (a previous assignment) and modify the function averageGrades() so that it does not take into account grades with the value -1. In this case, -1 indicates the assignment was not completed yet so it should not factor in the average.
I'm using a program called testbed to test my work. It acts like the user and compares the actual and expected results. I'm getting a rounding error on one test and passing others, and I'm not sure why:
Test 1
With one -1, there are 9 items to be averaged:
   90 + 86 + 95 + 76 + 92 + 83 + 100 + 87 + 91 = 800
   800 / 9 = 88.888 
Note we are working with integers here so the value gets truncated!

> Grade 1: 90
>   Grade 2: 86
>   Grade 3: 95
>   Grade 4: 76
>   Grade 5: 92
>   Grade 6: 83
>   Grade 7: 100
>   Grade 8: 87
>   Grade 9: 91
>   Grade 10: -1
>   Average Grade: 88%
>   Test 1 passed.

Test 2
There is one -1 in the list here, but it is in the middle.
   90 + 86 + 95 + 92 + 83 + 100 + 87 + 91 + 76 = 800
   800 / 9 = 88.888

> Grade 1: 90
>   Grade 2: 86
>   Grade 3: 95
>   Grade 4: -1
>   Grade 5: 92
>   Grade 6: 83
>   Grade 7: 100
>   Grade 8: 87
>   Grade 9: 91
>   Grade 10: 76
>   Average Grade: 89%\n
>   Exp: Average Grade: 88%\n
>   Test 2 failed.

Test 3
This is a special case. Since all the values are -1, the sum is 0.
However, if you try to compute the average, you will have 0/0.
Since we can't divide by zero, this will crash. You need to check
for this case with an IF statement

> Grade 1: -1
>   Grade 2: -1
>   Grade 3: -1
>   Grade 4: -1
>   Grade 5: -1
>   Grade 6: -1
>   Grade 7: -1
>   Grade 8: -1
>   Grade 9: -1
>   Grade 10: -1
>   Average Grade: ---%
>   Test 3 passed.
>   Failed 1/3 tests.
>   Finally: here's my code:

```
/***********************************************************************
* Program:
*    Assignment 31, Array Design
*    Sister Unsicker, CS124
* Author:
*    Lanie Molinar
* Summary: 
*    This program gets 10 grades from the user, averages them, and displays the
*    result.
*
*    Estimated:  2.0 hrs   
*    Actual:     1.5 hrs
*      I had some difficulty getting the style checker to not complain about 
*      my NUMGRADES constant. First, it didn't like the _ when I tried to 
*      name it NUM_GRADES, and when I tried using NUM-GRADES, it complained 
*      about there not being white space between operators. It finally stopped 
*      complaining when I used NUMGRADES.
************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NUMGRADES 10

/***********************************************************************
* The function getGrades gets 10 grades from the user, passing them to main().
***********************************************************************/
void getGrades(float grades[], int num)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      cout << "Grade " << i + 1 << ": ";
      cin >> grades[i];
   }
   return;
}

/***********************************************************************
* The function averageGradesGrades averages the grades inputted by the user
* and returns that value to main().
***********************************************************************/
void averageGrades(float grades[], int num)
{
   float sum = 0;
   int notCompleted = 0;
   int i = 0;
   cout.setf(ios::fixed);
   cout.precision(0);
   while (i < num && (i + notCompleted != num))
   {
      if (grades[i] != -1)
      {
         sum += grades[i];
         i++;
      }
      else
         notCompleted++;
   }
   float average = sum / (num - notCompleted)- 1;
   if (notCompleted != num)
      cout << average;
   else
      cout << "---";
   return;
}

/**********************************************************************
*    The main function calls getGrades and averageGrades and displays the 
*   result returned by averageGrades.
***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   float grades[NUMGRADES];
   getGrades(grades, NUMGRADES);
   cout << "Average Grade: ";
   averageGrades(grades, NUMGRADES);
      cout << "%\n";
   return 0;
}
```

I tried a few things before I posted this. I added the - 1 to my "float average = sum / (num - notCompleted -1)," and that fixed some things. My errors were a lot wores before that. I also converted many of the ints I had in here to floats, and that helped too, but nothing I do gets rid of that error.

Comment: There's a lot going on here... could you trim it down to something smaller that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Umm.. what?   tl;dr

Comment: Why the `-1` here: `(num - notCompleted)- 1`. Shouldn't it just be `(num - notCompleted)`? Btw, I believe this: `while (i < num && (i + notCompleted != num))` is not needed, it could just be: `while (i < num)` and move `i++;` out of the `if/else`.

Comment: If `grades[i] == -1` you never increase `i`, so you get stuck at that value.

Comment: When I tried this, which I think is close to what some of you suggested, I got two errors and not just one. My code now looks like:void averageGrades(float grades[], int num)
{
   float sum = 0;
   int notCompleted = 0;
   int i = 0;
   cout.setf(ios::fixed);
   cout.precision(0);
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      if (grades[i] != -1)
         sum += grades[i];
      else
         notCompleted++;
   }
   float average = sum / (num - notCompleted);
   if (notCompleted != num)
      cout << average;
   else
      cout << "---";
   return;
}

Comment: When I tried the above code, tests 1 and 2 both said 89 instead of 88%.

Comment: Your latest code looks OK to me except that you define `average` as a float. Since you want to truncate, just define it as int. Then when `sum / (num - notCompleted)` is calculated, it will automatically be truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this one out. Here's the code I came up with:

```
/***********************************************************************
* Program:
*    Assignment 31, Array Design
*    Sister Unsicker, CS124
* Author:
*    Lanie Molinar
* Summary:
*    This program gets 10 grades from the user, averages them, and displays 
*    the result. It doesn't count -1 as a completed assignment, so it won't 
*    count it when it computes the average.
*
*    Estimated:  2.0 hrs
*    Actual:     4.0 hrs
*      I had a lot of trouble making my code pass all 3 tests in testbed. I 
*      kept failing at least one every time. After working on it for a while,
*      though, I finally got it working.
************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NUMGRADES 10

/***********************************************************************
* The function getGrades gets 10 grades from the user, passing them to main().
***********************************************************************/
void getGrades(int grades[], int num)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      cout << "Grade " << i + 1 << ": ";
      cin >> grades[i];
   }
   return;
}

/***********************************************************************
* The function averageGradesGrades averages the grades inputted by the user
* and returns that value to main(). It doesn't count -1's as completed 
* assignments, and if the user enters -1 for all grades, it outputs dashes 
* instead of the average.
***********************************************************************/
void averageGrades(int grades[], int num)
{
   int sum = 0;
   int notCompleted = 0;
   int average;
   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      if (grades[i] != -1)
         sum += grades[i];
      else
         notCompleted++;
   }
   if (sum != 0)
      average = sum / (num - notCompleted);
   if (notCompleted != num)
      cout << average;
   else
      cout << "---";
}

/**********************************************************************
*    The main function calls getGrades and averageGrades and displays the
*   result returned by averageGrades.
***********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   int grades[NUMGRADES];
   getGrades(grades, NUMGRADES);
   cout << "Average Grade: ";
   averageGrades(grades, NUMGRADES);
   cout << "%\n";
   return 0;
}
```